# Generating the Nth combination of a binomial coefficient

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

I'm designing a protocol, and need a bit of help. I am able to neatly condense the problem I am having into a allegory, I hope it doesn't sound too contrived.

---

Alice has flipped a coin `t` times, and has told me it has landed on heads `k` times.

From this, I am able to figure out how many different possible combinations of ways that Alice could have got this result:

`function binom(t, k) {
    var coeff = 1;
    for (var i = t-k+1; i <= t; i++) coeff *= i;
    for (var i = 1;     i <= k; i++) coeff /= i;
    return coeff;
}`

but now Alice wants to tell me the precise combination of heads-and-tails to she got, however she is restricted to only telling me a single number, the `N`th possible way of generating the results she flipped.

So describe an algorithm that turns `t` (total coin flips), `k` (amount of heads) and `n` into a sequence of heads-and-tails.

There are multiple ways of ordering all possible combinations, so there are multiple answer. But in my case, it doesn't matter how Alice orders the combinations (and thus the N she gives me) as long as I have a procedure to efficiently decode it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested the following and it seems to work. It's in SQL as opposed to C but I hope you can follow the syntax. I'm not sure how much explanation you need but let me know if you have questions. The `dbo.Choose()` function is the same as your `binom()` function.

```
    -- Parameters
declare @t int; set @t = 8
declare @k int; set @k = 3
declare @n int; set @n = 7
    -- Variables
declare @seq varchar(8000); set @seq = ''
declare @m int; set @m = @n
declare @NumberOfCombinations int; set @NumberOfCombinations = dbo.Choose(@t, @k)
declare @HeadsRemaining int; set @HeadsRemaining = @k
declare @FlipsRemaining int; set @FlipsRemaining = @t
    -- .
    -- Work left-to-right: in each iteration, decide if the char is H or T, then
    -- set up the variables for the next iteration.
while @FlipsRemaining > 0 begin
    if @m <= @NumberOfCombinations * @HeadsRemaining / @FlipsRemaining begin
        -- Since C(t-1,k-1) / C(t,k) = k/t is the proportion of entries starting with H
        -- and same rule then applies at each subsequent level.
        set @seq = @seq + 'H'
        set @NumberOfCombinations = @NumberOfCombinations * @HeadsRemaining / @FlipsRemaining
        set @HeadsRemaining = @HeadsRemaining - 1
    end
    else begin
        set @seq = @seq + 'T'
        set @m = @m - @NumberOfCombinations * @HeadsRemaining / @FlipsRemaining
        set @NumberOfCombinations = @NumberOfCombinations * (@FlipsRemaining - @HeadsRemaining) / @FlipsRemaining
    end
    set @FlipsRemaining = @FlipsRemaining - 1
end
select @seq
```

This works on the following style of ordering, starting the H's leftmost and ending with H's rightmost. ($t=5, k=3$):

\begin{eqnarray*}
1 && HHHTT \\
2 && HHTHT \\
3 && HHTTH \\
4 && HTHHT \\
5 && HTHTH \\
6 && HTTHH \\
7 && THHHT \\
8 && THHTH \\
9 && THTHH \\
10 && TTHHH.
\end{eqnarray*}

So, $t=5,k=3,n=5$ results in HTHTH.